# webRTC createDataChannel throws a DOM exception in Chrome Canary

Tags: javascript, webrtc

I'm trying to create a data channel in the latest Chrome Canary (dataChannel flag is on).

```
var SERVER = "stun:stun.l.google.com:19302";  
var pc1 = new window.webkitRTCPeerConnection({"iceServers": [{"url": SERVER}]});
pc1.createDataChannel('my_channel');
```

Canary throws me the following exception : NotSupportedError: DOM Exception 9

Does anybody know why is that happening?

Comment: Use offer/answer model to exchange SDP/ICE....See this: https://webrtc-experiment.appspot.com/docs/how-to-use-rtcdatachannel.html .... or a Demo Chat: https://webrtc-experiment.appspot.com/chat/

Answer (score 0):

Chrome requires some connection constraints to be set to true. More specifically the "RtpDataChannels" constraint is the one that matters. Try to use it that way:

```
configuration = {'iceServers': [{'url': 'stun:stun.l.google.com:19302'}]};
connection = { 'optional': [{'DtlsSrtpKeyAgreement': true}, {'RtpDataChannels': true }] };
pc1 = new window.webkitRTCPeerConnection(configuration,connection);
pc1.createDataChannel('my_channel');
```